# Changing the border width of one div, but instead the border width of the next div changes

Tags: html, css

I've run into this strange "bug" when experimenting with different decimal border widths. They are actually pretty funny, but why changing the border of the first div (by 0.09px in my case), changes the border of the second div?

I've created two pairs of divs to show it:

```css
[id^=border]{
  width:100px;
  height:33px;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:15px;
}
#border1{
  border:1.4px solid black;
}

#border2{
  border:1.6px solid black;
}

#border3{
  border:1.49px solid black;
}

#border4{
  border:1.6px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="border1">bordered div 1</div><br>
<div id="border2">bordered div 2</div><br>

<hr>

<div id="border3">bordered div 3</div><br>
<div id="border4">bordered div 4</div><br>
```

The first div has the border width of 1.4px, and the second has 1.6px.

Then, I change the border of the the first div to 1.49px, it doesn't really seem to affect this div, which is not really strange, since 0.09px is a pretty small value. However the border width of the second div changes quite radically.

Maybe it just happens on Safari, here's the screenshot:

> [image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: which browser? they all look the same in chrome

Comment: Welcome to the world of subpixel rendering.

Comment: To be honest, to me they all look the same. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safari 7 on Mac. @Bri

Comment: Best practice cross-browser is to not use decimal pixels.  As you've found, it's not great when it does work, and in most browsers it doesn't work at all, rounding to the next nearest full pixel instead.

Comment: @holp Safari 7 on Mac.

Comment: look the same as well in FF38.0.5

Comment: For me they all look the same. But if you want, you can enable GPU acceleration to see what Safari will do (can't test here). To do this, add this CSS style to your elements: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); transform: translateZ(0);`

Comment: No repro on Safari 8.0.7 on retina MBP. What's your device pixel ratio?

Comment: At the moment, most browsers round the border width to the nearest pixel, both visually and when calculating the combined width of several elements; this may lead to all kinds of unexpected results, so I'm afraid it's best to avoid subpixel border widths. If you want to experiment with them anyway, IE seems to do it right, surprisingly. Chrome has strange rounding errors when setting sub-pixel margins e.g., and doesn't do sub-pixel borders.